# React Native: Animation when component unmounts

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a custom modal which slides in upon `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {

    Animated.timing(this._animatedValue.y, {
        duration: 200,
        toValue: 0
    }).start()

}
```

Ok, this was easy. However, I also like to slide the modal out when the component unmounts. For me, `componentWillUnmount()` would feel right, as it is an elegant declarative way:

```
componentWillUnmount() {

    Animated.timing(this._animatedValue.y, {
        duration: 200,
        toValue: deviceHeight
    }).start()

}
```

But this does of course **not** work, because the React doesnt wait until I have finished my animation.

So currently I work around this with a custom function:

```
closeModal() {


    Animated.timing(this._animatedValue.y, {
        duration: C.filterModalDuration,
        toValue: deviceHeight
    }).start()

   InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
     this.props.UnmountThisComponent()
   })

}
```

This is of course not as elegant, but it works. However, the pain begins if I need to call this function from a component far down in the component tree, i.e. I need to manually pass down this function via `onUnmount={()=> closeModal()}` and then with `onUnmount={this.props.onUnmount}` over and over again...

Then I thought that I could solve this with redux & redux-connect. I was thinking to trigger a redux state change from the child components, which would then call the function via `componentWillRecieveProps()` like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {

  if (nextProps.closeFilter === true) {
          this.closeModal()
  }

}
```

However this feels pretty hacky and imperative.

**Is there any way to solve this problem in an elegant / declarative way?**

Comment: Any update on this? I am in this same situation at the moment. If no updates could expand your code explanation bit more since I don't understand what is this InteractionManager etc :D

Comment: No update from my side. The interaction manager will first execute the callback after an animation is done. You would usually put expensive synchronous tasks inside that callback. If you would execute the animation and the expensive task at the same time, the animation will be janky. (Unless you use the native driver for animation which got released in recent versions of react native, which would execute the animations on a seperate thread). See more here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager.html

Comment: Are you using `Navigator` in your project? That's how we do animations (in transitions) on enter/exit views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not use `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` to execute after an animation completes. I recommend using the `start` callback.

`Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {}).start(() => this.props.closeModal())`

There are things like https://github.com/mosesoak/react-native-conductor which can help you coordinate deep animations and fire back up. This takes advantage of `context`.

You could also use redux as you have tried however I would use `componentDidUpdate` rather than `componentWillReceiveProps`.

The reason is that it is only safe to cause a `setState` in the component you have your `componentWillReceiveProps` in.

If you trigger a `dispatch` inside of `componentWillReceiveProps` it will cause a `setState` in other components cause your application to break.

Overall: I would recommend this flow. (Close Action Initiated) => Animate Modal Closed => in `start(() => {})` callback cause a `setState` or set a piece of data in your `redux` store that will then `unmount` your modal which is now hidden.

This way you get the unmount animation.

If you are using routing like `react-navigation` I recommend setting up a `mode: "modal"` navigation style. That way the unmounting/mounting modal animations are taken care of for you.

Answer (score 3):

`componentWillReceiveProps` seems to fit perfectly as it's intent is to make actions based on next props. This is ideal when parents want to trigger actions on their childrens (even through this is not really the pattern of React where children call parents functions, and parents receive events from childrens).